# Invalid outside procedure vba excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to code a macro to put the last modified date into an excel cell before closing the document.

Here is my code:

```
Private1

 Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
     Range ("A1" = ThisWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Last Save Time"))
 End Sub
```

The error comes up: Invalid Outside Procedure.

Please, help me fix this.
Thank you.

Comment: Delete the Private1 line.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
Private1

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Range ("A1" = ThisWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Last Save Time"))
End Sub
```

use

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Range("A1") = ThisWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Last Save Time")
End Sub
```